# Spring Boot JPA with CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Good afternoon, I am creating a REST API and I have a problem to implement Spring JPA's CrudRepository. I can not consume the API with JSON, 406 Not Aceptable in POSTMAN, I'm confused, because with DAO it works for me, but with an implementation of JPA no, I have some wrong concept.

I describe the problem:

IDE - STS

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1949174611236850070L;

    @Id
    @Column (name = "id_usuario")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUsuario;

    @Column(name = "usuario")
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name = "clave")
    private String clave;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido;

    @Column(name = "foto")
    private String foto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPrivilegio")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Privilegio privilegio;

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public Usuario(String usuario, String clave, String nombre, String apellido, String foto, Privilegio privilegio) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.clave = clave;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.foto = foto;
        this.privilegio = privilegio;
    }

    public Long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(Long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public Privilegio getPrivilegio() {
        return privilegio;
    }

    public void setPrivilegio(Privilegio privilegio) {
        this.privilegio = privilegio;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    public Usuario findByUsuarioAndClave(String usuario, String clave);
    public Usuario findByUsuario(String usuario);
}
```

Service:

```
Service("usuarioService")
@Transactional
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public List<Usuario> findAll() {
        return (List<Usuario>) usuarioRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Usuario findByUsuarioAndClave(String usuario, String clave) {
        return usuarioRepository.findByUsuarioAndClave(usuario, clave);
    }

    public void save(Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    }

    public Usuario findByUsuario(String usuario) {
        return usuarioRepository.findByUsuario(usuario);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sg-v1")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService _usuarioService;

    //GET
    @RequestMapping(value="/usuarios", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=aplication/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> getUsuarios(
            @RequestParam(value="usuario", required=false) String usuario) {
        List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        if (usuario == null) {
            usuarios = (List<Usuario>) _usuarioService.findAll();
            if (usuarios.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>>(usuarios, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        else {
            Usuario user = _usuarioService.findByUsuario(usuario);

            if (user == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }

            usuarios.add(user);

            return new ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>>(usuarios, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        String response = "Bienvenido a <a href = 'http://soliddev.com.ar'>soliddev.com.ar</a> !";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of Spring?

Comment: in postman, right under the send button, there's an orange link `code` that pops up a window with a curl command, can you paste it here? sounds more like you are not querying it correctly rather than an error on the server

Comment: @msagala25 Version is 4.3.12.RELEASE

Comment: @LuisRamirez-Monterosa code: curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:8080/sg-v1/usuarios/?usuario=admin' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: aa1bf6e5-aae7-1225-c6df-6c531907cb20'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your @RequestMapping

`produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8"`

with spring boot you can use

`@GetMapping(value = "/usuarios")`

and will do it for you out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ResponseBody` in the method, so it can return your **Object** in the request as `JSON`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/usuarios", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=aplication/json")
@ResponseBody // Add this
public ResponseEntity<List<Usuario>> getUsuarios(@RequestParam(value="usuario", required=false) String usuario) {
//
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens, I update the thread with the maincontroller where if I get an answer (not in json).